# Quality Loss when convert SVG to WMF

Tags: inkscape, file-conversion

I created a simple symbol in InkScape and I want to convert it to WMF.
But there is a loss of quality in the conversion.

I attached the link to download 2 files. The original SVG and the WMF output. Look at the result. [Download Images](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Xcz9wfiOIhm6JAwZ1XHO_UcNQEt81kjM?usp=sharing)

The strange thing is that this problem started to occur a few days ago on my machine.

Has anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately Google Drive says "Access Denied".  Also I suspect only the simplest SVGs will work as WMF.  Make sure there are no path effects, clipping paths, masks, clones, or anything like that, and that text is converted to outlines.

Comment: Hi! I fixed the link! There is no effect on the SVG, just a circle and a shape drawn with the Bezier tool

Comment: Try exporting it as EMF (Enhanced MetaFile) instead.  WMF can't handle curves well.

Comment: Moth emf and wmf gave really limited precision. Try scaling the vector up and then back down. Or for even better results paste the SVG into PowerPoint  its better

Comment: @joojaa - it actually doesn't look too bad when exported straight to EMF, I just checked.  However it's not perfect, so the scaling up trick seems like a good idea. WMF is hopeless, maybe adding a few hundred extra nodes would help smooth it out a bit.

Comment: Guys... try to write an actual answer :o)

Comment: @Rafael - ok, done!!!

Answer (score 6):

Don't use WMF. It's a very old format, and it can't handle curves properly - in fact it doesn't seem to support curves at all.  It might be possible to add nodes to help smooth everything out, but it's probably not worth your while unless you must use WMF.  You can use the Edit Paths by Nodes Tool <kbd>N</kbd> to do this, select all the nodes, then hit the Insert New Nodes button several times.

Instead, try exporting as EMF (Enhanced MetaFile).

I just tried this in Inkscape and it works much better, although it's not perfect. You could do as joojaa suggests in his comment: scale the SVG artwork up before exporting to EMF. This will help the precision. Then when you import it, scale the image down to size.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only going to speak in generalities here to shed some light on the problems and possible solutions, and not get into the specifics of one drawing or way of saving a file. Understanding these terms and formats is 99% of the battle in creating, transferring, and displaying high-quality images in the digital world.

To maintain the scalability and smoothness of vector drawings, which is what SVGs are, you must use a graphics file format that supports vector drawings, and also use a conversion method that preserves all the vector information.

WMF stands for Windows Metafile. A "metafile" format supports both vector and raster (bitmap) information. But the vectors in WMF are only line segments, not smooth curves. Even worse, the conversion can toss even that limited vector information away; the result is the same as taking a screen shot. That is, it converts the vector drawing into a raster image at the current resolution of the monitor.

Taking a screen shot of an image after zooming in (assuming the monitor is large enough) and then scaling the result downward is one way to improve the resolution and reduce the "jaggendness" of an image when converting it.

The most popular file formats that support vector graphics are EPS, SVG, AI native (Illustrator), and PDF.

The way you display/output a file must also support vector graphics, or the advantages of vector graphics (smoothness, scalability, device independence) are lost upon output. The display software/hardware must convert the vector information into pixels. This hardware/software was referred to as a RIP (raster image processor) in high-end equipment. A RIP takes vector formulas and makes a raster image at the highest resolution of the output device, which is typically a digital imagesetter that uses film, or a digital platemaker that exposes printing plates directly.